# Rails 7.0.3 is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<https://raw.github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/master/composer.rb>:279:in `apply': Rails 7.0.3 is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer. (StandardError)
```

Rails version 7.0.3
Ruby version 3.1.2

Comment: Rails Composer is 4+ years old. Support for Rails 6 was requested in 2019. You *could* try fork-hunting, but it seems effectively dead.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the lines 264 to 280 of that file you will find the following `case` block:

```
# this application template only supports Rails version 4.1 and newer
case Rails::VERSION::MAJOR.to_s
when "5"
  say_wizard "You are using Rails version #{Rails::VERSION::STRING}. Please report any issues."
when "3"
  say_wizard "You are using Rails version #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} which is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
  raise StandardError.new "Rails #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
when "4"
  case Rails::VERSION::MINOR.to_s
  when "0"
    say_wizard "You are using Rails version #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} which is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
    raise StandardError.new "Rails #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
  end
else
  say_wizard "You are using Rails version #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} which is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
  raise StandardError.new "Rails #{Rails::VERSION::STRING} is not supported. Use Rails 4.1 or newer."
end
```

This block only checks if the major Ruby on Rails version is `"3"`, `"4"`, or `"5"`. For all other version numbers it will return the error message that you got, no matter if the number was lower (like `"2"`) or higher (like `"6"` or `"7"`).

Apart from the fact that this check is not done well, it is certainly outdated. I suggest contacting the maintainer of that file to have a look.

Or you could try to clone and fix the file allowing newer versions too. But keep in mind that there is no guarantee that this file would work with newer versions out of the box. It is not unlikely that the file needs to be changed to support newer versions.